# Перенос текста в WebView

Tags: webview, android

Встал такой вопрос:
У меня есть `WebView` и нужда показывать широчезную страницу, где про `<br/>` не слышали.

Водить влево-вправо утомительно. Необходимо реализовать перенос текста, основываясь на масштабе и размере экрана. Вопрос: как?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Никакого штатного решения нет. Мне на ум пришло только вытащить из вебвью `html`, обернуть его в

```
<div style="width:100%">...</div>
```

И засунуть обратно

Comment: С самой страницой не вариант. Надо на стороне клиента. Да и что выйдет, если громадную страницу с таблами, графой и т.п. в наглую сжать?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте `webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN)` - по идее весь текст должен ужаться в одну колонку по ширине порта

Comment: Попробую и отпишусь через час

Comment: Взялся я за слишком сложный код...
Не могу понять куда пхать, в коде уже вроде есть такое, но оно работает кусками: половина переноситься. половина нет.

Comment: @Martin_Devil - это нарушение правил форума - предложение фриланса. За такое можно и бан получить.

Comment: Фриланс-фриланс. Эхех, а где-же ещё найти реально шарящих людей, а не очередную школоту? Ладно, Sorry.

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо.